# Java-Apache BufferedHttpEntity loads whole file when sending the request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient

I want to make a Multipart request to my server from java using the apache `CloseableHttpAsyncClient`, this is what i currently have:

```
File file = new File("pathname");
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new FileInputStream(file), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "file");
multipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody("filename", "File one");
HttpEntity multipartEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
BufferedHttpEntity buffEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(multipartEntity);
```

But when uploading a large file it throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` and i see it occupy all my machine memory ( Process goes from 100Mb memory to 3000+Mb ).
I have also tried to replace

```
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new FileInputStream(file), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "file");
```

with

```
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", file);
```

But this has limited content length and gives the error "Content length is too long".
So how do I upload a large file (50gb+) using apache `CloseableHttpAsyncClient`?

**EDIT**

As suggested, i removed the BufferedHttpEntity but now i get the error "Content Length unknown". If i add a header with content length it tells me that content length header is already present.

**EDIT 2**

If i change the line

```
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new FileInputStream(file), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "file");
```

to

```
multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file", fileContentBody);
```

I get the error that Content length is too long

Comment: You are mixing up an an async transport with a blocking entity implementation. You need to build an async multipart entity producer or use the classic (blocking) transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error i ended up switching to the `CloseableHttpClient` with `RequestBuilder` and `HttpUriRequest` instead of `HttpPost` to execute the request in a blocking way on a thread.

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
FileBody fileContentBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, file.getName());
multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file", fileContentBody);

multipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody("filename", "File number one");
HttpEntity multipartEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();


HttpClientContext context = new HttpClientContext();
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = RequestBuilder.post("Myurl.com");
requestBuilder.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
HttpUriRequest multipartRequest = requestBuilder.build();

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(multipartRequest, context);
```